# Postgres server is not responding to a nodejs request

Tags: postgresql, node.js

I have access to a remote postgres DB from pgAdmin4 and I also could access from nodejs using a Mac. Right now I'm using the same code to access the DB in Windows. The code for my connection is the following:

```
const { Client } = require('pg'); //Importing the Postgres package
const hosts= require('../hosts'); //Using the file containig all hosts 
const connectionData = { //Begin creating the connection settings object
   host: hosts.DBHost, //DB host   
   port: hosts.DBPort, //DB hosts port
   database: hosts.DB, //DB
   user: hosts.DBUser, //DB user
   password: hosts.DBPassword, //DB user password
 }
```

My test is the following:

```
var client = new Client(connectionData); //New client instance using the above connection settings
client.connect(); //Open the connection to the database()  
sql = "select * from myTable";
client.query(sql) 
  .then(response => {
    console.log ({"data": response}); //This isn't shown 
  })
  .catch(err => { 
    console.log({"error": err}); //This isn't shown neither 
  })
```

No error, no exception, the DB server doesn't respond!

Why isn't the server responding?

Comment: What happens if you use the client.connect() with a callback like in the documentation to get error messages logged during connection? https://node-postgres.com/api/client

Comment: I didn't test it. Let me do this. Thanks.

Comment: I found the solution here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611039/postgres-server-is-not-responding-to-a-nodejs-request?noredirect=1#comment108987882_61611039

Comment: Please write up your solution as an answer and then mark it as correct - this may help others with the same problem in the future! p.s. welcome to the forum!

Comment: Just doing that. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that I have `Nodejs 12` in my Mac, but I have `NodeJS 14` in my Windows, so it's a compatibility problem.

Since I updated my postgres (`pg`) to `8.0.3` or superior (`i.e. npm install pg`), now it works!

One guy helped me to realise that issue in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61611039/postgres-server-is-not-responding-to-a-nodejs-request?noredirect=1#comment108987882_61611039.